# Convert YYYY-MMM-DD into DD/M/YYYY in excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, time, cell

I would like to ask for a way to convert YYYY-MMM-DD HH:MM:SS into DD/M/YYYY HH:MM:SS in excel. My data is basically extracted from an application which converts into excel. The cell for the date/time seems to be fixed and i'm unable to change the formatting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> My data is basically extracted from an application which converts into excel.

No, it doesn't convert. The reason the format appears fixed is due to the fact that the datetime is coming in as text-that-looks-like-a-datetime, not a real datetime.

In an unused column to the right use this formula,

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1, 4), SEARCH(MID(A1, 6, 3), "   janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec")/3, MID(A1, 10, 2))+
 TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1, 8))
```

Fill down then copy and paste special values back to the original column.

[image: datevalue_timevalue]

Note that the true datetimes hold a default right-alignment in the cell like any other number while the text-that-looks-like-a-date is left-aligned. Don't forget to format the cells as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.